# Should I add engine's code to the app itself if I'm going to modify it a lot (Spree, Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree, rails-engines

I'm starting a new app with Spree and I'm going to heavily modify it. 
It seems impractical to go to source every time I need to change something.

Should I just copy paste contents of **spree/front_end** engine to my app or should I do:

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do
  def some_method
    ...
  end
end
```

**class_eval**s all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my recent Spree project there **class_eval**s everywhere.

This is probably a question of how you are going to maintain Spree versions upgrade (assuming you are going to modify it heavily). If you are much interested in keeping Spree version up-to-date its better to try using Deface and as less monkey patching as it possible, organizing code as extensions.

But if there is really a lot of changes and it is not so important to be able to upgrade Spree version (it used to happen) you should not waste much time for it.

Anyway, there is less advantages in full copying models and controllers - this is enough to patch needed method (but to remember, that if you upgrade and did not change method directly, something may fail).

But views (and Deface) is quite complicate to be heavily changed, so you should consider to copy them entirely (and remember that this can break some extensions).

Comment: thanks for this, it's very important to see how someone has done it to be more sure of what you are doing. it's not important to keep this app updatable in my case, I'm sure I'll be copying the views over, but was not quite sure of what should I do with controllers and models.

Comment: Not copying controllers and models code entirely only makes you to be aware of Spree changes to modify methods you relying on. If you`re not going to update Spree version, you should not copy all the code - it will make your code-base to be less which will increase maintainability